# Missing gem 'cgi (>= 0) ruby'

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rails

Everything was working, but today I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'cgi (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

I have ruby1.9.1-dev installed.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? what is the command you ran, that gave you this error?

Comment: it's rails bundle problem. When I try to run 'bundle install' in project directory it shows my this error instead of installing missing gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to install the "cgi" gem. It ships with Ruby, so there's no need for that step. Just "require"-ing it should be sufficient.

Comment: I have gem 'cgi' in Gemfile file, when I run 'bundle install', I get this error.

Comment: You were right, problem solved!